# How to build autocomplete similar-title check like stackoverflow?

Tags: yii, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using [Yii PHP framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). When you ask a question on stackoverflow, as you type the title a list appears called "Questions that may already have your answer".  I want to create similar type of field so that when users enter the name of a business I can display similar business names already in my system.  It doesn't necessarily need to be as sophisticated as stackoverflow's model.  A simple alphabetical search should be fine.

Keep in mind unlike a normal autocomplete, this "autocomplete" won't actually fill in the field in question but rather serves as an informational tool to inform the user of data that potentially already exists.

I'm thinking [Yii CJuiAutoComplete widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete/) is the right tool for the job but how do I dissociate the autocomplete from the input field?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by dissociate? the autocomplete doesn't actually fill the field until a value is selected from the suggestions. what sort of characteristic are you looking for?

Comment: @bool.dev exactly the way the stackoverflow site works as you type in a new question.  With stackoverflow you cannot "select" an existing title to use as your question title, rather it's just showing you what's already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CJuiAutoComplete is definitely the right tool, and to disable the auto filling when selecting the suggested values, you will have to alter jQueryUI autocomplete's behavior for its [`select` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), and also for its [`focus` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus).

The `select` event is triggered when a suggestion item is clicked, and `focus` event is triggered when a suggestion item is navigated to by keystroke (up, down arrow keys).

So to change the default behavior, which is updating the text field, you can cancel those events by returning false from their callbacks:

```php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    // other options
    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
            return false;
        }',
        'focus'=>'js:function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }'
    ),
));
```